# NameError: name 'data' is not defined (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-preprocessing

I am running this code in Python, I don't know what its always error

```
import string
import nltk
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Prihantoro Tri N\OneDrive\Documents\file toro\MSIB\Magang\Hukumonline\Project\youtube comments\dataset_komentar_instagram_cyberbullying.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

def casefolding(comment):
    comment = comment.lower()
    comment = comment.strip(" ")
    comment = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!_:")(-+,]', '', comment)
    return comment
data['comment'] = data['comment'].apply(casefolding)
data.head(100)
```

And the results give the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 8>()
      6     comment = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!_:")(-+,]', '', comment)
      7     return comment
----> 8 data['comment'] = data['comment'].apply(casefolding)
      9 data.head(100)

NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

or the results are like this >> KeyError: 'comment'

Comment: it is literally written in the title of your very own post

Comment: so what is the correct code?

Comment: define data before you access it!

Comment: What do you think that `data` should be? We have no idea after reading your post.

Comment: idk too, but i already update my question. hope you guys can help me

Comment: Are you sure there is a column named `'comment'` in your csv?

Comment: For your updated question: show us the output of `data.head()` and `[*data.columns]` BEFORE applying the non-working line.

Answer (score 1):

I think your dataframe don't have `"comment"` column so please try check all the columns in your dataframe.
try to run this `data.columns`

Answer (score -2):

#lets say your is from a csv file

import pandas as pd

import re

df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv')

data = pd.DataFrame(df)

def casefolding(comment):

```
comment = comment.lower()
comment = comment.strip(" ")
comment = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!_:")(-+,]', '', comment)
return comment
```

data['comment'] = data['comment'].apply(casefolding)

data.head(100)

Comment: i try your code but its same that got an error results, can you look my question up there, I already update it

Comment: convert the data to dataframe, data = pd.DataFrame(data) and do data.columns to see if column comment exist